# Is there a library available to read stabs debug information?

Tags: c++, gcc, debug-symbols

It's easy to generate the stabs debug information using GCC, but is there a library available to parse and read it again to get some information about the underlying code of the compiled program?

Comment: Maybe libdwarf? http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html

Comment: Also see the *stabs* specs: http://docs.freebsd.org/info/stabs/stabs.pdf

Comment: Libdwarf reads (surprise) DWARF format. At least quick look at it's source code does not revel a word `stabs` anywhere. The only program that does it is `objdump`, the code to read STABS in in the main C file, so no, it is not a library. I am also interested in making it into a library, but do not have time for that, there are few thousand lines of relevant code.